# SQL server Job error while running SSIS solution

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, ssis, kingswaysoft

I have tested a SSIS solution with kingswaysoft in SSDT, and it is fine but when this to be run through SQL Server, it throwing error like-
Value cannot be null.
Parameter-Identityprovider
at ttn.jxp(Object abl,String abm)
at tvi'1.jnc(ttr air)
at tvi'1.jmw(ttr aih)
at tvi'1.jnt(ClientCredentials ajo)
at tzh.pgr(Boolean cvz,Nullable'1 cwa)
at tzh.fyh.cjr()
at tpo.yia[cb](Func'1 ed,Int32 ee,Func'2 ef,Func'2 eg,Func'1 eh,PipelineComponent ei)

Comment: Do you have the Kingswaysoft components installed and licensed on the server that is executing the job? Do you have the same 32/64 bit version of the software installed on the server as your development environment? Are you executing the SSIS package in the same bit mode as the kingswaysoft software?

Comment: This is likely related to the runtime missing the login credentials. Make sure that you have specified the connection credentials using SSIS configuration for the job. If you continue to have the issue, please reach out to our support team, we will try to assist you from there.